# Want to redirect to some page automatically in php

Tags: php

When I submit a form.php it call insert.php. And insert.php insert form data in database and echo a message "record successfylly added.". I want that after displaying this message automaticllay retrieve to the form.php. I also commented the line where i have to redirect.

```html
My form.php

    <html>
<body>

<form action="insert.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="myname"><br>
Comment: <input type="text" name="mycomment"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>

My insert.php

    <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","commentdb");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security
$firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['myname']);
$lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['mycomment']);


$sql="INSERT INTO person (Name, Comment, Time)
VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', NOW())";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

echo "1 record added";
// Here it should retrieve
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: You can use a header, but you won't be able to echo a message also, since that would be outputting before header. If you want both echo and redirect, you will need to use JS or a meta refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redirect to another page with PHP using the `Location` header.

Be careful to remove any echo before the header. You can't use `header()` after output started (and this is useless if you plan to redirect visitor).

Example :

```
header("Location: form.php");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using header function :

```html
header( "refresh:10;url=form.php" );
```

page will be redirect after 10 second.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Kevin's comment concerning use of Location.  I have a site built with this where I pass messages from the 'control' (insert.php in your case) to the 'View' (form.php in your case).

In the 'Control' i set a session variable with the message, eg:

```
            $_SESSION["mess"] = "BOOK0015";
```

and then use:

```
header ("Location:UIATbooks.php?id=".$authorid)
```

to move back to my 'View'.

In the 'View' I look for messages and display, eg:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['mess'])) {
    $mess = $_SESSION['mess'];
  }
  else {
    $mess = "";
  }
  if ($mess != "") {
    $objmess = new clsmessage ();
    echo '<p><span class="style3">'.$objmess->returnmess ($objscreen->connection,$mess).'</span></p>';
    unset($_SESSION['mess']);
  }

$objscreen->endscreen ();
```

I have a class that stores the message based on ID.